# In Power BI, how to return a list of rows from a table (or create a dynamic table) where text is found within a free text field in another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, sql-like

I have a table, **Defender**, with a column, **Device Name**

I have another table, **Defender SNOW**, which has a column, **Short Description** (which is a text field).

The **Short Description** contains free text. I want to be able to lookup **'Defender'[Device Name]** and check if it appears anywhere in the **'Defender SNOW'[Short Description]** field.

I can do this with the following calculated column:

```
Has SNOW Ticket = 
    IF(
        ISEMPTY(
            FILTER(
                'Defender SNOW',
                CONTAINSSTRING(
                    'Defender SNOW'[Short description],
                    Defender[Device Name]
                )
            )
        ),
         FALSE(),
         TRUE()
    )
```

I can then lookup the **'Defender SNOW'[Number]** column to return the reference number of the record where the device name exists.

```
Has SNOW Ticket Ref = 
    IF(
        ISEMPTY(
            FILTER(
                'Defender SNOW',
                CONTAINSSTRING(
                    'Defender SNOW'[Short description],
                    Defender[Device Name]
                )
            )
        ),
        BLANK(),  -- or you can use 0 or any default value based on your requirement
        MAXX(
            FILTER(
                'Defender SNOW',
                CONTAINSSTRING(
                    'Defender SNOW'[Short description],
                    Defender[Device Name]
                )
            ),
            'Defender SNOW'[Number]
        )
    )
```

However, I want to be able to return multiple entries from the **'Defender SNOW'** table, if the **[Device Name]** is found in multiple records in the **[Short Description]** field, and show the multiple **'Defender SNOW'[Number]** in a table on a Power BI tab.

(In SQL, I would use a **Select....where 'Short Description' Like '%[Device Name]%'**)

Is it possible to do this?

Alternatively, is it possible to create a dynamic table, which is will list all records in the 'Defender SNOW' table where 'Defender'[Device Name] exists in Short Description? I could then just show that dynamic table in a visual/power BI tab.

So, for example, the source tables and the expected/desired resulting dynamic table would look like this:

[image: Defender Links to SNOW table]

Thanks for any pointers,

Mark

Comment: Can you paste your tabular data as copiable text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Measure with:

```
SNOW count = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Defender SNOW'),
    CONTAINSSTRING('Defender SNOW'[Short Description], SELECTEDVALUE('Defender'[Device Name]))
  )
```

Then add this new measure to your Table visual.

[image]

**Note** you will get a visual error complaining that a relationship couldn't be determined - this will disappear as soon as you add the measure to your visual.